# error while using springloaded in jboss startup

Tags: jboss, wildfly, spring-loaded

I am using springloaded agent in jboss and it is giving me error in startup. Error is related to logmanager and desvribed in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded/issues/94. I am able to resolve this issue after making following changes in standalone.conf

```
JBOSS_LOG_MANAGER_LIB="$(echo $JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-*.jar)" # resolve logmanager jar

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xbootclasspath/p:$JBOSS_LOG_MANAGER_LIB  -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman,org.jboss.logmanager,org.springsource  -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager" # register jboss logmanager at jvm early startup
```

Is there a way i can relocate package in springloaded jar using maven shaded plugin so that there will be no more additional settings required.
I have tried relocating java.util.Logger but nothing works. 
Is there any other way i can make some changes in spring loaded to avoid this custom settings for jboss.

Answer (score 0):

No I don't think you have any other option as JbossLogManager has to be registered as the LogManager.
You might try  "-Dorg.wildfly.logging.skipLogManagerCheck" option, but I'm not sure this would be sufficient.